# About this scene in Elizabeth Harvest?

Tags: plot-explanation, elizabeth-harvest

In the movie Elizabeth Harvest, there is a scene where Elizabeth enters the forbidden room (this is the second time around). This time she ends up waking the next clone. The next clone wakes up with this confidence about herself. Walks around and finds Elizabeth sleeping.

My 3 Questions are:

1. How is Elizabeth deep in sleep that quick?
2. How is this clone so sure of herself right outside the tank but in the end she seems to be a confused wreck with a gun.
3. What is the significance of the clone trying to take off the clothes from Elizabeth? She wakes up with her pyjamas pulled down.

To summarize the context - I'm trying to understand the relevance of the scene with the clone waking up (the three events). The clone appears to be trying to do something specific but after this scene she doesn't show up till the end. The purpose of this scene appeared irrelevant to the film otherwise.

Comment: It might be possible that your "3 questions" might be related to each other somehow, but for all I know you're asking 3 quite different questions at once here, which isn't how these sites normally work. Maybe you can draw the connection between these idividual questions and how they're relevant for answering the bigger picture (whatever that may be) a little clearer?

Comment: Done, made the edit